# Static application as part of frameworkless di

Tags: android

as part of writing android apps I want to use dependency injection. I am neither happy with frameworks like koin, dagger or hilt and want to try to go with no framework. In Android there is the problem that an application context is needed for everything. I came up with the solution to save the application statically. I am not sure myself if this can be done safely so I ask you.

```
class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Di.initialize(this)
    }
}
object Di {
    fun initialize(app: Application) {
        this.app = app
    }
    lateinit var app: Application
    val context by lazy<Context>{app}

    val myRepo by lazy { Repo(context) }
}
class Act:Activity() {
    override fun onCreate (...) {
        super.onCreate(...)
        Di.myRepo.push("hello")
    }
}
```

What do you think? Safe to use?

Comment: "Safe to use?" -- safe with respect to *what*? It is not thread-safe, for example.

Comment: With respect to: is it possible to leak an application that way? Thanks for pointing out thread-safety. I didn't thought about that yet.

Comment: I checked your point of thread-safety. objects are threadsafe since they are created in the static initializer. lazy vals are threadsafe because by default they are synchronized. The only point that I see is left is the app variable. This would be fixed by calling it volatile since I don't expect anything running concurrently to the application.oncreate. Did you mean something else?

Comment: "lazy vals are threadsafe because by default they are synchronized" -- ah, I was not aware of that. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to leak an application that way?

The `Application` object is a process-wide singleton. Effectively, it is pre-leaked. You cannot leak it further by holding references to it.